# error after submitting app saying : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have submitted a react native App to google play internal testing , these tests show some Stability errors , the same aab file installed on my device and works just fine , debug mode also works fine with no errors , but at google play internal testing it shows errors saying :

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Lcom/facebook/jni/HybridData;" field
> "mHybridData" in class "Lcom/shopify/reactnative/skia/SkiaDomView;" or
> its superclasses

and another one saying :

> Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity
> {com.imagewatermarks/com.imagewatermarks.MainActivity}:
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to
> add unknown view tag: 199  detail: View tag:239 View Type:class
> com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup   children(1): [ 193,  ],
> viewsToAdd(1): [ [1,199],  ],   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded
> (ActivityThread.java:4896)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:4845)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity
> (ActivityThread.java:4796)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute
> (PauseActivityItem.java:46)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState
> (TransactionExecutor.java:176)   at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
> (TransactionExecutor.java:97)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2144)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.Interrogator.loopAndInterrogate
> (Interrogator.java:10)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil
> (UiControllerImpl.java:7)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil
> (UiControllerImpl.java:1)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadForAtLeast
> (UiControllerImpl.java:7)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap (Tap.java:4)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform
> (GeneralClickAction.java:4)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform
> (ViewInteraction.java:2)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform
> (ViewInteraction.java:23)   at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.-$$Nest$mdoPerform   at
> androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call (ViewInteraction.java:6)
> at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call
> (ViewInteraction.java:1)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run
> (FutureTask.java:266)   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
> (Handler.java:938)   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
> (Handler.java:99)   at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:240)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8000)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:603)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:947) Caused by
> com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to
> add unknown view tag: 199  detail: View tag:239 View Type:class
> com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup   children(1): [ 193,  ],
> viewsToAdd(1): [ [1,199],  ],

I read somewhere that the errors related to proguard file so they suggested to add some lines of code to my file so here is my proguard-rules.pro file :

```
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.ModuleRegistryHolder { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaScriptExecutor { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.ExecutorToken { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableType { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.react.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.facebook.react.** { *; }
```

and here is code from my /android/app/build.gradle:
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true
....

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

and from my android/build/build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
 buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 30
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

after generating new aab file and submitting it these changes did not make any effect still the same errors show up in google play internal testing , could you please see if you can help . thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone facing similar issue I have solved that by adding to my prodguard file  the class that fired the error , here it is :

> -keep class com.shopify.reactnative.skia.SkiaDomView {*;}

and it worked.